# In loop, make it so all the other values except the one that matches the condition to be given styles

Tags: javascript

I have a calendar and right now I have it so the current day results in that column being highlighted. However, I also need to make it so all the days that are not the current day, to give the column that it's in a different background color than what the column that is the current day, is highlighted in.
Here is my code so far:

```js
let today = new Date();
var d = today.getDay();
var weeks = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
  var currentWeek = weeks[i].children;
  if (d < currentWeek.length) {
    currentWeek[d + 1].style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="time">time</th>
      <th class="sun" id="sunday">sun</th>
      <th class="mon" id="monday">mon</th>
      <th class="tue" id="tuesday">tue</th>
      <th class="wed" id="wensday">wed</th>
      <th class="thu" id="thursday">thu</th>
      <th class="fri" id="friday">fri</th>
      <th class="sat" id="saturday">sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="8:00AM">8:00 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="8:30AM">8:30 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:00AM">9:00 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:30AM">9:30 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="10:00AM">10:00 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="10:30AM">10:30 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="11:00AM">11:00 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="11:30AM">11:30 AM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="12:00PM">12:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="12:30PM">12:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="13:00PM">1:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="13:30PM">1:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="14:00PM">2:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="14:30PM">2:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="15:00PM">3:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="15:30PM">3:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="16:00PM">4:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="16:30PM">4:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="17:00PM">5:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="17:30PM">5:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="18:00PM">6:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="18:30PM">6:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="19:00PM">7:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="19:30PM">7:30 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="20:00PM">8:00 PM</td>
      <td class="sun"></td>
      <td class="mon"></td>
      <td class="tue"></td>
      <td class="wed"></td>
      <td class="thu"></td>
      <td class="fri"></td>
      <td class="sat"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hello @Kai, can you explain a little better what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want all days different than today to be colored and not today or do you want all day to be colored but in different colors?

Comment: Hey, I want want all days different than today to be colored and not today

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading correctly, you want to have the days that are not hot-pinked another color. How about already default changing the color of the box?

```js
let today = new Date();
        var d = today.getDay();
        var weeks = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
            var currentWeek = weeks[i].children;
            if (d < currentWeek.length) {
                currentWeek[d + 1].style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
            }
        }
```

```css
.sun, .mon , .tue , .wed, .thu, .fri, .sat {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th class="time">time</th>
            <th class="sun" id="sunday">sun</th>
            <th class="mon" id="monday">mon</th>
            <th class="tue" id="tuesday">tue</th>
            <th class="wed" id="wensday">wed</th>
            <th class="thu" id="thursday">thu</th>
            <th class="fri" id="friday">fri</th>
            <th class="sat" id="saturday">sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="date" id="8:00AM">8:00 AM</th>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="date" id="8:30AM">8:30 AM</th>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="9:00AM">9:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="9:30AM">9:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="10:00AM">10:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="10:30AM">10:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="11:00AM">11:00 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="11:30AM">11:30 AM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="12:00PM">12:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="12:30PM">12:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="13:00PM">1:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="13:30PM">1:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="14:00PM">2:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="14:30PM">2:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="15:00PM">3:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="15:30PM">3:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="16:00PM">4:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="16:30PM">4:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="17:00PM">5:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="17:30PM">5:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="18:00PM">6:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="18:30PM">6:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="19:00PM">7:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="19:30PM">7:30 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" id="20:00PM">8:00 PM</td>
            <td class="sun"></td>
            <td class="mon"></td>
            <td class="tue"></td>
            <td class="wed"></td>
            <td class="thu"></td>
            <td class="fri"></td>
            <td class="sat"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I want to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default class to all days and overwrite current day:

```js
let today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDay();
    var weeks = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
      var currentWeek = weeks[i].children;
      if(i>0){
        weeks[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        currentWeek[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }      
      if (d < currentWeek.length) {
        currentWeek[d + 1].style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th class="time">time</th>
      <th class="sun" id="sunday">sun</th>
      <th class="mon" id="monday">mon</th>
      <th class="tue" id="tuesday">tue</th>
      <th class="wed" id="wensday">wed</th>
      <th class="thu" id="thursday">thu</th>
      <th class="fri" id="friday">fri</th>
      <th class="sat" id="saturday">sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="date" id="8:00AM">8:00 AM</th>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="date" id="8:30AM">8:30 AM</th>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date" id="9:00AM">9:00 AM</td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
      <td class="day"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't use css for this, only javascript.

Comment: Removed css block